# Simplifying the scalar product of $f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^7(c_n\cos\left(nt\right))$ with itself ($\langle f, f\rangle$)

Tags: fourier-analysis, inner-products, orthogonality

How can simplify this equation so that

$$\left\langle\sum _{n=0}^7c_n\cos\left(nt\right),\:\sum \:_{n=0}^7c_n\cos\left(nt\right)\:\right\rangle$$

becomes

$$\pi \left|c_0\right|^2+\frac{\pi \:}{2}\sum \:_{n=1}^7\left|c_n\right|^2$$

> My attempt

$$\left\langle\sum _{n=0}^7c_n\cos\left(nt\right),\:\sum \:_{n=0}^7c_n\cos\left(nt\right)\:\right\rangle$$

$$=\sum \:_{n=0}^7\left(\sum \:\:_{n=0}^7\left|c_n\right|^2\langle \cos\left(nt\right),\:\cos\left(nt\right)\rangle\right)$$

$$=\sum \:_{n=0}^7\left(\sum \:\:_{n=0}^7\left|c_n\right|^2\int _{_0}^{\pi }\cos^2\left(nt\right)dt\:\right)$$

$$=\sum \:_{n=0}^7\left(\sum \:\:_{n=0}^7\left|c_n\right|^2\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$$

I don't know how to go on from here.

Comment: Why are you using the same $n$ in both sums?

Comment: Am I not supposed to have two sums? I'm not sure how it should be otherwise.

Comment: Use `langle` and `rangle` instead of $<$ and $>$. $\langle f, f\rangle$ looks much better than $<f,f>$. And why are you adding space between the summation symbol and its index?

Comment: I never ever use LaTeX besides when I ask questions on StackExchange so that's not my main focus.

Comment: Instead of 7, I'd suggest trying 2 or 3 instead and do it by hand. Then you will understand @MichaelBurr 's comment

Comment: You are supposed to have two sums, but you shouldn’t use the same $n$ twice.  You are missing terms this way, ones of the form $\cos(nt)\cos(mt)$.